# Why does my FactoryGirl callback run when it shouldn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am using FactoryGirl 3.3.0 with RoR 3.2.3

I have a user model which has_one profile like so;

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, update_only: true
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_attributes
  before_create :build_profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true, on: :update
  validates :last_name, presence: true, on: :update
end
```

In my rspec tests I need to sometimes prevent the before_create :build_profile from running so I can have a user without a profile. I manage this with a FactoryGirl callback

```
after(:build) {|user| user.class.skip_callback(:create, :before, :build_profile)}
```

My user factories are defined as follows;

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) {|n| "user_#{n}@example.com"}
    sequence(:username) {|n| "user_#{n}"}
    password "secret"
    factory :user_with_profile do
      factory :new_user_with_profile do
        before(:create) {|user| user.activated = false}
      end
      factory :activated_user_with_profile do
        before(:create) {|user| user.activated = true}
      end
    end
    factory :user_without_profile do
      after(:build) {|user| user.class.skip_callback(:create, :before, :build_profile)}
      factory :new_user_without_profile do
        before(:create) {|user| user.activated = false}
      end
      factory :activated_user_without_profile do
        before(:create) {|user| user.activated = true}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My expectation was that the `:new_user_without_profile` and `:activated_user_without_profile` would inherit the `after(:build)` callback from `:user_without_profile` while the `:new_user_with_profile` and `:activated_user_with_profile` factories would not, but it's not quite working like that. Here's an excerpt from the console to demonstrate my problem;

```
irb(main):001:0> user = FactoryGirl.create :new_user_with_profile
irb(main):002:0> user.profile
=> #<Profile id: 11, first_name: "", last_name: "", created_at: "2012-07-10 08:40:10", updated_at: "2012-07-10 08:40:10", user_id: 18>
irb(main):003:0> user = FactoryGirl.create :new_user_without_profile
irb(main):004:0> user.profile
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> user = FactoryGirl.create :new_user_with_profile
irb(main):006:0> user.profile
=> nil
```

So, the first time I create a :new_user_with_profile, a profile is created as expected but the second time (after creating a :new_user_without_profile), it doesn't any more! The after(:build) callback doesn't seem to be getting called again (if I add some code to it to output something, I don't see it in the terminal). I have no idea what's going wrong here. Does anyone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a dirty solution but have you tried to write the definition of the callback in the `factory :user_with_profile`:

```
after(:build) {|user| user.class.set_callback(:create, :before, :build_profile)}
```

Does it work?

Comment: No I hadn't tried that and yes it does work. Thanks, that at least gets my tests working. It really is a dirty solution though - I'd prefer to understand what's actually going wrong here.

Comment: What happens here is really straightforward. See that `user.class.skip_callback(:create, :before, :build_profile)` declaration of yours? Because the callbacks are set on the class and not on the instance of the class, when you first call `FactoryGirl.create :new_user_without_profile` it sets to skip the callback. Later when you call `FactoryGirl.create :new_user_with_profile` it naturally has no callback set because you have previously deleted. My suggestion is to set it back, that's all.